# Excel: Consecutive 3 Occurrences or more of a value in a string

Tags: excel

Need to calculate the count of instances where 0 has occurred consecutively 3 times or more.

i.e.

```
CAR_NO  1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

In the above case the Cell A1 is CAR_NO and B1:R1 are either 0 or 1. I need the count of instances where 0 has occured 3 times or more.

Final Output is 2. AS B1:D1 has 3 times 0 occured and M1:P1 has 4 times 0 occured.

Comment: Where does SQL come into this?

Comment: This problem is platform independent. I have this dataset uploaded in my Local DB as well.

Comment: So are you looking for a solution in SQL or excel VBA? Have you tried writing any code so far?

Comment: Shall we use Excel VBA? so that we can create UDF and find it easily...

Answer (score 2):

Using Base R: 
`rle` function compute the lengths and values of runs of equal values in a vector.

```
x <- c(1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1)
rlx <- rle(x)

rlx
Run Length Encoding
    lengths: int [1:9] 1 3 2 2 1 1 1 4 2
    values : num [1:9] 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

sum(rlx$lengths[x==0] >=3, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 2
```

PS: @Mr. Down voter answer posted as OP "Original post" includes `R` tag.

Comment: nice using just `base::`!

Answer (score 1):

Excel vba udf

args:

*arg1* ***rng*** range to count over e.g. A1:R1. Must be 1 row wide.

*arg2* ***consecutiveRun***. # of consecutive instances required. Default value 3.

*arg3*  ***searchValue***. Value to match on for consecutive run. Default value 0.

```
Public Function GetCount(ByVal rng As Range, Optional consecutiveRun As Long = 3, Optional searchValue As Variant = 0) As Variant
    Dim arr(), i As Long: arr = rng.Value
    If UBound(arr, 2) < consecutiveRun Or rng.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        GetCount = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If
    For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2) - consecutiveRun
        If Not (IsEmpty(arr(1, i))) And arr(1, i) = searchValue _
           And Not (IsEmpty(arr(1, i + 1))) And arr(1, i + 1) = searchValue _
           And Not (IsEmpty(arr(1, i + 2))) And arr(1, i + 2) = searchValue Then
            GetCount = GetCount + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

---

Data:

[image: Data]

Comment: What happens if you delete the values of the cells in `A1:R1` and run the UDF?

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA

```
Function getCount(byVal Rng as Range) As Long
    Dim str As variant

    str = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Rng.Value))
    if isarray(str) then str = Join(str, "")
    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
      .Global = True
      .ignorecase = True
      .MultiLine = True
      .Pattern = "0{3,}"
      getCount = .Execute(str).Count
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, seeing as there's a MySQL tag (perhaps this is one for code golf)...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table 
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,CAR_NO INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (car_no) VALUES
(1),(0),(0),(0),(1),(1),(0),(0),(1),(0),(1),(0),(0),(0),(0),(1),(1);

SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id
            , car_no
            , CASE WHEN @prev = car_no THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END i
            , @prev:= car_no 
         FROM my_table
            , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY id
     ) x 
 WHERE i = 3;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        2 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

...oh, or just...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id
            , car_no
            , CASE WHEN car_no = 0 THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=0 END i
         FROM my_table
            , (SELECT @i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY id
     ) x 
 WHERE i = 3
```